# Metabase to Snowflake Connection

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, database-connection, metabase

I am trying to connect Metabase to Snowflake but getting the below error :

```
JDBC driver encountered communication error. Message: Certificate for <mja55108.us-east-1.aws.snowflakecomputing.com> doesn't match any of the subject alternative names: [*.prod3.us-west-2.snowflakecomputing.com, *.us-west-2.snowflakecomputing.com, *.global.snowflakecomputing.com, *.snowflakecomputing.com, *.prod3.us-west-2.aws.snowflakecomputing.com].

Acccount name : mja55108.us-east-1.aws
Provding correct user name and password.
```

I am not sure about the RSA private key (PKCS#8/.p8) ? Local File Path.

Answer (score 1):

As per the account locator formats table in the [docs](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/admin-account-identifier#non-vps-account-locator-formats-by-cloud-platform-and-region), if your account is on AWS US-east-1, it should not have `.aws` part in the account name, leave it just like:

```
xx12345.us-east-1
```

Comment: After removing `.aws`part getting timeout error.

Comment: Do you have a firewall? Check if you can access your account via the full URL like``` xx1234545.us-east-1.snowflakecomputing.com```

Comment: It should just be `xx12345` without anything after that.

Comment: @kingmilo depends on the region and cloud platform. [doc](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/admin-account-identifier#non-vps-account-locator-formats-by-cloud-platform-and-region)